# Retrieving local storage variable and using it in ng-bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage, currency

I'm trying to learn javascript by doing this project but i have hit a snag,

I have set a exchange rate in local storage

```
localStorage.gbpUSD = "1.42746";
```

and i am trying to use it instead of the hard coded exchange rate below....

```
<input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" ng-model="GBP" 
value="" placeholder="">

<ion-item menu-close="">USD
<span class="amountFloat" ng-bind="GBP * 1.42746 | number : 2"></span>
</ion-item>
```

I have tried this...

```
var gbpUSD = localStorage["gbpUSD"];
```

and..

```
<ion-item menu-close="">USD
<span class="amountFloat" ng-bind="GBP * gbpUSD | number : 2">1</span>
</ion-item>
```

But it doesn't do anything, I'm probably missing something so simple, can anyone help?

Comment: gbpUSD must be property of scope to be able to use it in `ng-bind`

Comment: use `$scope.gbpUSD` instead of `var gpbUSD`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [localstorage's setItem and getItem methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) or possibly angular's [$cookies service](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) if you want to later store items rather than just strings.